# Total Distance of points drawn on JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to print total distance like you can see i have  page.drawString("Distance: " + fmt.format(length), 10, 15); in my code. But that adds only length from only point1 to point2. I want it to keep adding for example i draw a line from point 1 to point 2 which had a distance of 30 and then again drew a line from point 1 to point 2 which had a distance of 20 so my drawString should show 50 as a result.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class RubberLinesPanel extends JPanel {

    private Point current = null, point2 = null;
    private double length;
    private DecimalFormat fmt;

    public RubberLinesPanel() {
        LineListener listener = new LineListener();
        addMouseListener(listener);
        addMouseMotionListener(listener);
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
    }

     public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
        super.paintComponent(page);
        page.setColor(Color.yellow);
        if (current != null && point2 != null)
        page.drawLine(current.x, current.y, point2.x, point2.y);
        page.drawString("Distance: " + fmt.format(length), 10, 15);
    }

    private class LineListener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            current = event.getPoint();
        }
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        // Gets the current position of the mouse as it is dragged and
        // redraws the line to create the rubberband effect.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
            point2 = event.getPoint();
            length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((current.x - point2.x), 2) +
            Math.pow((current.y - point2.y), 2));
            repaint();
        }
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        // Provide empty definitions for unused event methods.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: PLEASE AVOID USING ALL UPPER-CASE SINCE IT IS EQUIVALENT TO **SHOUTING** ON THIS AND OTHER SITES. thanks

Comment: I've edited your question title and have removed the all-caps.

Comment: i see shouting huh lol

Comment: but that was not solution to my question

Comment: No, but it might help get more eyes to see your question, increasing your odds of getting an answer. You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to simply give your class a `double totalDistance` field, initialize it to 0, and then add each calculated length to the totalDistance field immediately after calculation.

```
public class RubberLinesPanel extends JPanel {
    private Point current = null, point2 = null;
    private double length;
    private double totalDistance = 0.0;  // ***** add this *****
    private DecimalFormat fmt;

    public RubberLinesPanel() {
        // .... etc .....
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
        super.paintComponent(page);
        page.setColor(Color.yellow);
        if (current != null && point2 != null)
            page.drawLine(current.x, current.y, point2.x, point2.y);
        page.drawString("Distance: " + fmt.format(length), 10, 15);

        // draw totalDistance here  // ************ draw it here
    }

    private class LineListener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            current = event.getPoint();
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
            point2 = event.getPoint();
            length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((current.x - point2.x), 2)
                    + Math.pow((current.y - point2.y), 2));
            totalDistance += length;   // ******* calculate it here
            repaint();
        }
```

Or did I over-simplify your problem, because this solution seems too simplistic?

Comment: thanks for the help buddy you rock. it was so simple i was making loops lol